# Program to update all 3rd party software packages?

Tags: windows-7, software-update

Is there a program that can check for updated versions of various application packages? I currently have 123 different packages and its a pain to keep them up to date manually. Mainly what I want from it:

- Ability to update all packages from one program and not use several programs in conjunction.
- Ability to choose where each package gets downloaded(i have 4 different folders for them).
- Ability to only check for updates but not download anything.
- Ability to download to a file(so when a filename is pre-set then the package is downloaded into it and i save the trouble of renaming via batch files etc.)
- Preferably open source,lightweight on resources and regularly maintained and updated(please don't offer dead projects)

Currently I have found these that could potentially fit my demands but I haven't tested them yet very much.

http://www.kcsoftwares.com/?sumo

http://ketarin.canneverbe.com/

My system is Windows 7 x64.

Comment: Sounds an awful lot like yu... oh wait, Windows. Never mind.

Comment: @Ignacio: I get the feeling that you're suggesting a package manager (For Linux of course) but what does 'yu' mean?

Comment: It's the first two letters of "yum".

Comment: Ok SuMo is out of the question.It opens browser tabs with download links.I want all downloads to be done by the program itself on the main program window, not trough browser etc...

Gonna look more carefully at Ketarin now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok.Ketarin is the one.
I have managed to do everything i wanted and can imagine.Very happy with it.
I am almost finishing up the extremely long configuration and testing process.
It has been about week and several hours of continious work each day, but this is waht i've done:

*96 packages(reduced from the original 123 since i deleted the unnessesasy ones).
*17 packages are marked as Manual since updating them is technicly very complex.
*21 packages that are packed as .zip.I have written special extraction and rename commands for each of those to be run after one of them is updated and is downloaded.
*Rest are .msi/.exe packages and the install command for these after download is much simpler.
*Version numbers are extracted from official wesites(during update check) and placed in a custom column for easy overview.
*Files are saved with the latest version number and naming scheme.This fully accounts for any changes that might occur(if version number changes on the website and Ketarin detects that the remote package date and/or time has changed then the file is downloaded,given the latest version number and executed for install.

It has taken a long time to configure but since there wont be need for any major rewrite in the forseeable future then i'm pretty sure that within months i have saved all that time i spent on configuring and then some.

If you need any help with Ketarin then let me know and i see if i can help you.I'm still learning new this as i go along but so far it seems like a very flexible program that can be suited to any need.

Answer (score 1):

Does [Appsnap](http://genotrance.wordpress.com/applications/appsnap/) work for you ?

Comment: The latest version seems more than 2 years old...